# mapping my external ip to a registered dns name

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, mapping

Praveen here ,I have registered  www.abc.com and i have my web server sitting at our corporate office  aand a  public ip mapped to it . i am able to access the application from the external network directly typing the ip address , but i want to access this application using the registered dns name ie abc.com fromt the external network, upon typing    the abc.com where it  should directly  go the public ip and open up the application sitting in there.

Can anyone help me in this , how to do it step by step...

Comment: Please learn something about the DNS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Answer (score 3):

You need to use your domain registrar's tools to create DNS A records that point your domain name to your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your domain registrar's site ---> Under your domain(abc.com), click manage domains----> Now add your A record as

@    your-ip

here '@' specifies your domain name.